# How to create user without password and set it later with Devise form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm building a Rails app and I want to create users on the rails console WITHOUT password, receive a confirmation email, and by clicking on the link in the confirmation email, set the password on my website. (I'm using Devise)

Here is what I tried so far:

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable

  protected
  def password_required?
    confirmed? ? super : false
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/users/confirmations_controller.rb**

```
class Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  protected
  def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
    sign_in(resource)
    edit_registration_path(resource)
  end
end
```

I specifically did `sign_in(resource)` because I want people to be signed in during the process.

**app/controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def create
    end
end
```

For the moment, when I create a user through the rails console and then click the confirmation link, I end up in the devise view, to edit my account (more specifically my password), which is great, but I can't validate the form since I have to fill my previous password to change it. But since I don't have set any password during the creation I'm stuck!

Any ideas about how I could this?

Thanks

**EDIT**

As mentioned in the comment, I tried to use the "forgot my password" link. It works, but after setting their password, user will have to sign in (so enter again their password). In my opinion, it might not be a very good customer experience, that's why I would like to know if there's a way to do it as I explained in my post, OR a way to sign in the user after he set his password for the first time.

**UPDATE**

After some suggestions, I did some changes in my files, but I still get the error saying that the current password can't be blank. Here is my code:

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'page#index'

  devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_in: 'sign_in', sign_out: 
  'sign_out'}, controllers: { confirmations: 'users/confirmations', 
  registrations: 'users/registrations' }
end
```

**app/controllers/users/confirmations_controller.rb**

```
class Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  def update_resource(resource, params)
    if resource.encrypted_password.present?
      super
    else
      resource.update(params)
    end
  end

  protected
  def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
    sign_in(resource)
    edit_registration_path(resource)
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable

  protected
  def password_required?
    confirmed? ? super : false
  end
end
```

**app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb**

```
<h2>Edit your account</h2>

<div>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
    <p><%= current_user.first_name %> <%= current_user.last_name %></p>
    <p>Email address: <strong><%= current_user.email %></strong></p>

    <div class="container mb-5">
      <div class="row">
        <%= f.label :password %>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <%= f.password_field :password, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', :required => 'required' %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container mb-5">
      <div class="row">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', :required => 'required' %>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="container text-center mb-3">
      <%= f.submit "Update", class: 'navbar-cta' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**logs**

```
Started GET "/edit" for ::1 at 2020-01-20 18:06:29 +0100
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#edit as HTML
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 33], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering devise/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
DEPRECATION WARNING: [Devise] `DeviseHelper.devise_error_messages!`
is deprecated and it will be removed in the next major version.
To customize the errors styles please run `rails g devise:views` and modify the
`devise/shared/error_messages` partial.
 (called from _app_views_devise_registrations_edit_html_erb___445667363343301985_70311530657080 at /Users/victor/Documents/SaaS projects/ChurnTarget/app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb:6)
  Rendered devise/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 7.3ms | Allocations: 1979)
  Rendered layouts/_google_analytics.html.erb (Duration: 0.4ms | Allocations: 164)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered page/_navbar.html.erb (Duration: 1.9ms | Allocations: 669)
  Rendered page/_footer.html.erb (Duration: 0.8ms | Allocations: 162)
Completed 200 OK in 226ms (Views: 221.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms | Allocations: 61076)


Started PUT "/" for ::1 at 2020-01-20 18:07:00 +0100
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"99pJ5XaS5k5NQmba31GrTu5+jeN57mdPV51XlG6WFJoizS/5rbeLerzmTQv+kbsPIPorjH9fjAz3ihPxXENo1w==", "user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Update"}
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 33], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 33], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Unpermitted parameter: :password_confirmation
  Rendering devise/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
DEPRECATION WARNING: [Devise] `DeviseHelper.devise_error_messages!`
is deprecated and it will be removed in the next major version.
To customize the errors styles please run `rails g devise:views` and modify the
`devise/shared/error_messages` partial.
 (called from _app_views_devise_registrations_edit_html_erb___445667363343301985_70311530657080 at /Users/victor/Documents/SaaS projects/ChurnTarget/app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb:6)
  Rendered devise/shared/_error_messages.html.erb (Duration: 2.0ms | Allocations: 441)
  Rendered devise/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 7.5ms | Allocations: 1514)
  Rendered layouts/_google_analytics.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 8)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered page/_navbar.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 15)
  Rendered page/_footer.html.erb (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 5)
Completed 200 OK in 208ms (Views: 40.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms | Allocations: 20837)
```

Tell me if there are other files that you would like to see.

Comment: We do it through the "Forgot my password?" link, which we display as "First time access or forgot your password" which sends an email to the user so that they can set their own password.

Comment: Indeed, that would work of course, but, correct me if I'm wrong, the user will not be signed in after setting for the first time their password. I really want to avoid that, as setting your password and then logging in again might seem strange... Maybe you know a way to sign in the user after he set his password for the first time? Thanks.

Comment: The **Solution 3** is what you are looking for? https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password

Comment: This could do the trick indeed. However, I have some troubles implementing it. I followed what they did in the link you provided (solution 3) but I get a routing error: `No route matches {:action=>"update_password", :controller=>"devise/registrations", :format=>"31"}`

Comment: For me, the user is signed in after setting their password. I think there are Devise options to prevent the user from being signed in, but by default, he *is* signed in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A different solution altogether would be to use [`Devise::Invitable`](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) that provides the feature that you're probably looking for.

It gives you a `/users/invitations/new` path with a form that you can fill out which invites users. The user record is saved and then the user completes the registration process by accepting the invitation.

If you **really** wanted to you could send the invitations from the console with:

```
User.invite!(email: 'someone@example.com')
```

But really I would just setup some basic authorization with Pundit or CanCanCan to lock down the invitations controller and do it through the GUI. You're most likely going to need it anyways.

Comment: I didn't know about this gem. I'll try it and keep you updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
module Users
  class RegistrationsController < ::Devise::ConfirmationsController
    protected
    # By default Devise requires a password check on update.
    # this override checks if there is stored password so that
    # a confirmed user without a password can add their password
    def update_resource(resource, params)
      if resource.encrypted_password.present?
        super
      else
        resource.update(params)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`update_resource` is called in [`Devise::ConfirmationsController#update`](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/83a32e6d2118b0535cf54b48df4f9853d85b55fd/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L46). By default it calls [resource.update_with_password(params)](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/83a32e6d2118b0535cf54b48df4f9853d85b55fd/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L83) which monkeys around with the params and adds an validation error if the current password is not valid. Its not effected by `password_required?` since this special "validation" is done as part of the controller flow.

This just bypasses it if there is no saved password.

You need to configure the routes as well:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
  confirmations: 'users/confirmations',
  registrations: 'users/registrations'
}
```

Comment: Where should I put the first code you provided? In `app/controllers/users/confirmations_controller.rb`?

Comment: Mmmh I still get the error saying: `Current password can't be blank`. I will update my post to show more details. Maybe you'll see something that I did wrong!

Comment: Check the logs and ensure that the correct controller is being called.

Comment: The logs are in my post. In particular, I can see: `Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#edit as HTML` and then `Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#update as HTML` which is the correct controller I assume

Comment: Try stepping into `update_resource` with ByeBug or Pry and check if `resource.encrypted_password.present?` is returning true for some reason. I also added another answer with a completely different approach.